# Do I need NSManagedObject classes if I already have a plain old class?

Tags: core-data, swift4, nsmanagedobject

I have an app that didn't start off using Core Data. Now I'm integrating Core Data.

I have a plain old class and that is used through out the app. So I can't get rid of it but also don't need to. It's properties do match the Core Data entity attribute names.

Is it necessary to inherit from `NSManagedObject` and supply `@NSManaged` to the properties of the class? What value does that add in this case?

One problem is that not all of the plain old class properties are exactly the same types as those in the Core Data Entity. So I have to a transformation when going from the class to Core Data and vice versa.

Is there some way for Core Data to do the transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it necessary to inherit from NSManagedObject and supply @NSManaged to the properties of the class? What value does that add in this case?

Yes it is absolutely necessary because Core Data only works with instances of `NSManagedObject` or subclasses of `NSManagedObject`.

> One problem is that not all of the plain old class properties are exactly the same types as those in the Core Data Entity. So I have to a transformation when going from the class to Core Data and vice versa.

If your properties are types that conform to `NSCoding`, you can make them Core Data "transformable" properties and it'll just work. If they aren't, the easiest option would be to try and add `NSCoding` conformance to the types. If that's not possible, you can create a custom subclass of `NSValueTransformer` and configure Core Data to use it for your property.